# changing the Navigation Bar controller text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationitem

I am trying to change the navigation bar controller text (by default this is the title of the previous controller)

in other words in need to change the "back" text in [this image](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/UINavigationController-Tutorial.png) .

I tried several possibilities but none of them capture the new text :

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

OR

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

OR

```
[[bar backItem] setTitle:@" New Title "];
```

OR

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"New Title";
```

OR

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title=@"New Title";
```

am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the context to check, but try referring to it as the leftBarButtonItem.
Like this:

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setText:@"SomethingSomethingDarkside"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```